# How to map/serialize data in dynamodb via python?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Based on aws documentation , https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/python_3_dynamodb_code_examples.html, i'm using boto3 client to create/update data in a dynamodb table. dynamodb supports string, numbers , lists ,sets and boolean (see sample below) . based on the example, i'm setting an item , with a boolean . but i get an error that expected value for attribute is string, but i'm trying to set it as a boolean true/false value. how do i construct my request , such that i can set a boolean value in dynamo db via python? I understand the item is a python dictonary, i can set string values but not boolean?

```
db = boto3.client('dynamo')
        try:
            db.put_item(
                Item={
                    "year": year,
                    "title": title,
                    "info": {"plot": plot, "rating": Decimal(str(rating))},
                     "rating" : 42,
                     "award" : {"BOOL": False}
                }
            )
        except ClientError as err:
            logger.error(err)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are using a mixture of data types with the low level client, which supports DynamoDB-JSON only.

Have a read of this blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/exploring-amazon-dynamodb-sdk-clients/

Using low level client would be:

{'mybool': {'BOOL': False}}

```
dynamo = boto3.client('dynamodb') #dynamodb not dynamo
try:
       dynamo.put_item(
        TableName='MyTable',
        Item={
            "dob": {"N": "1985"},
            "name": {"S": title},
            "info": {
                "M": {
                    "email": {"S": "abc@xyz.com"},
                    "phone": {"S": "12093849393"}
                }
            },
            "paid": {"BOOL": False}
        }
    )
except ClientError as err:
     logger.error(err)
```

High level client:

'mybool' : False

```
dynamo = boto3.client('dynamodb') #dynamodb not dynamo
table = dynamo.Table('MyTable')
try:
    dynamo.put_item(
     Item={
      "dob": 1985,
      "name": "title",
      "info": {
           "email": "abc@xyz.com",
           "phone": "12093849393"
       },
        "paid": False
     }
    )
except ClientError as err:
     logger.error(err)
```